# How to load iptables rules.v4 file

Tags: iptables

I've been trying to initiate a `rules.v4` file that I have written a handful of rules into, but I can't seem to get the rules to load with

```
sudo iptables-restore < /file/path/rules.v4
```

I have saved the rules with

```
sudo iptables-save > /file/path/rules.v4
```

Now, when I check my table rules with `iptables -L --line-numbers`, my previous table rules are still there.

How do I get this file to load?

Comment: I [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14505455) about this on Stack Overflow. Your commands seem to be the same, but did you use `sudo` on this? IPTables is not something you can generally change as a regular user. Also, try running `iptables -F`, check it with `iptables -L -n` and then try to use `iptables-restore` again.

Comment: yes I always use sudo, , but however i didn't flush my previous rules maybe that's what it was. thanks a bunch.!